# If patch does not exist, random left turn. If patch does exist, and color is orange or green, move toward that patch

Tags: netlogo

I am having trouble executing this code and hope someone can help. Like the title says, my problem is to move people (turtles). If the patch ahead does not exist, then make random left turn. If the patch ahead does exist, and is green or orange, move toward that patch, if it is not green or orange, make a random left turn.

Here is my code:

```
ifelse is-patch? patch-ahead 1
and member? pcolor [green orange]] of patch-ahead 1
[fd 1]
[lt random 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
to setup
create-turtles 1 [ set color green ]
end

to move
ask turtles [
  let ahead patch-set patch-ahead 1
ifelse 
  any? ahead and any? ahead with [pcolor = black or pcolor = green]
  [fd 1]
  [lt random 1]
]
end
```